# Getting error after adding resilience4j-reactor in the dependencies

Tags: resilience4j

Resilience4j version: 1.1.0

Java version: 1.8.0_221

Problem description:
I am trying to use Resilience4j with WebFlux.

I have added the following dependencies and did not add any Resilience4j specific code yet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the following error while starting the server:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: io.github.resilience4j.bulkhead.autoconfigure.BulkheadAutoConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:413)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at com.walmartlabs.example.ExampleAppContext.<init> (ExampleAppContext.java:55)
    at com.walmartlabs.example.Example_Main.main (Example_Main.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
```

Answer (score 1):

resilience4j comes with multiple capabilities like circuit breaker, retry, rate limiter, bulkhead.

If you dont want all those features and want only fallback mechanism please go ahead and add the dependencies below in pom.xml file:

```xml
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>resilience4j-reactor</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>resilience4j-ratelimiter</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>resilience4j-bulkhead</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>io.github.resilience4j</artifactId>
                        <groupId>resilience4j-timelimiter</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ratelimiter</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bulkhead</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>io.github.resilience4j</artifactId>
                        <groupId>timelimiter</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
to
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>

Comment: Pleae add some details with your answer to better explain it.

Answer (score 0):

> Missed the below dependency.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below :

First of all, add this property in the  tag.

```
<resilience4jVersion>1.7.1</resilience4jVersion>
```

Add the below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-retry</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-circuitbreaker</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-ratelimiter</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-bulkhead</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-cache</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>resilience4j-timelimiter</artifactId>
        <version>${resilience4jVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```